# Error: "Invalid property type" while checking TextInput

Tags: kivy-language

I'm trying to check if user's TextInput is empty but getting error "Invalid property type". I'm programming in kivy.

My kv code:

```
<Label>
    font_size: self.height * .15
    background_color: (59/255,191/255,174/255,1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    color: (0/255,0/255,0/255,1)

<TextInput>
    multiline: False
    input_filter: "int"
    font_size: self.height * .15
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: (192/255,251/255,243/255,1)
    color: (0/255,0/255,0/255,1)

<Button>
    font_size: self.height * .25
    color: (0/255,0/255,0/255,1)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
    size_hint: (1, .3)
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: (8/255, 122/255, 111/255, 1)


<MyLayout>

     BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 1
        spacing: 1

    TextInput:
        id: calc_output
        text: "waiting for data..."
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'center'
        font_size: self.height * .20
        color: (0/255,0/255,0/255,1)
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        size_hint: (1, .3)

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 1
            spacing: 1

            Label:
                text: "Broj rođenih"

            TextInput:
                id: N
                
                                    
            Label:
                text: "Broj umrlih"

            TextInput:
                id: M
                

            Label:
                text: "Broj stanovnika prve godine"

            TextInput:
                id: bspg


            Label:
                text: "Broj stanovnika druge godine"

            TextInput:
                id: bsdg


    Button:
        text: "Definiraj tip općeg kretanja stanovništva"
        on_press: root.tipopceg()
```

I tried to check it with:

1. if - else
2. while not
3. try - except
4. if len()...

Everything I tried I would put in this part of code:

```
<TextInput>
    multiline: False
    input_filter: "int"
    while not id:
        print("You forgot...")
        break
```

or inside every TextInput

```
Label:
    text: "Broj rođenih"

TextInput:
    id: N
    while not N:
        print("You forgot...")
        break
```

but every time I get same error. Since I'm new in this world of programming, I guess I made some minor mistake why program doesn't recognize "id" of every user's TextInput and return error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: where is the bit of code you use to check if TextInput is empty ?

Comment: Didn't put it, I will fix my question now.

Comment: Have you been able to run the code before and see the interface ? How did you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm missing something here as well, but ain't kivy a library ? I think the whole purpose of kivy is to make a interface in a more practical way and separated from your logic statements, so the kivy language is  made only for interface creation. In that case, I think you are supposed to write your logic part using python, and then call your widgets if you want to make any operation with their properties.

I suggest you take the user input through python, and then use it to define a property of the widget:

```
self.userinput = TextInput(multiline=False)
```

Now you can take the property TextInput.text as the actual text inputed by the user. You can check if it's blank with:

```
if len(self.userinput.text) == 0:
    #do something
```